# StoreKit how to test originalAppVersion

Tags: ios, swift, storekit

I'm trying to check the original app version that the user installed so they can have unlocked premium features without paying twice.

In StoreKit for iOS 16 there's an "originalAppVersion" property on a transaction:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/apptransaction/3954447-originalappversion?changes=_8_2

Unfortunately this, and the "appVersion" property in development both return "1".

I was expecting a string of the form "1.0.5".

Do I need to do something different?

Comment: The documentation clearly states that the property contains the value of [CFBundleVersion](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/cfbundleversion?changes=_8_2). Are you sure that the value for CFBundleVersion in your Info.plist is 1.0.5 and not 1?

Comment: I’m pretty sure it is the major version with that variable not the minor version. You need to change the major version

Comment: @DávidPásztor I misread, thanks. Is there a way of reading the original app version's CFBundleShortVersionString?

Comment: @SweetSour unfortunately no

Answer (score 0):

I have found that in Sandbox it gives the current project version settings on MacOS and confusingly the current project build setting on iOS.

Here's the code:

```
do {
    let shared = try await AppTransaction.shared
    if case .verified(let appTransaction) = shared {
        print("\(appTransaction.originalAppVersion)")
    }   
} catch {
    print(error.localizedDescription)
}
```

And my project settings are:
Version: `1.1.0`
Build: `123`

On the Mac it prints: `1.1.0`

On iPad/iOS it prints: `123`